# The [templates] tag has been burninated/re-tagged away into [character-templates]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Apparently we had a [templates](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templates) tag on these questions:

- [How many templates can be applied to a summoned creature(s)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87887/how-many-templates-can-be-applied-to-a-summoned-creatures) (asked September 2016)
- [Where can I find extra templates for pathfinder?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88048/where-can-i-find-extra-templates-for-pathfinder) (asked September 2016)
- [Can a PC apply a template to a construct gained as a class feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93696/can-a-pc-apply-a-template-to-a-construct-gained-as-a-class-feature) (asked January 2017)
- [How to create a custom Lycanthrope in HeroForge Anew?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94633/how-to-create-a-custom-lycanthrope-in-heroforge-anew) (asked today, February 2017)

We already have the [character-templates](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-templates) tag for this stuff so I've burninated the [templates](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templates) tag and replaced it on these questions with [character-templates](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-templates).

I feel that [templates](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templates) is also way too generic a tag name to have around (or make a synonym of anything specific) since we could also have document templates, design templates, etc.

(This is tagged [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) but the burnination has already been done.)

Comment: Except many of these aren't characters, would creature-template be more accurate?

Comment: I'm with mxyzplk, PC's are creatures and so are most monsters.

Comment: @mxyzplk Sure, creature-templates works too. I figured monsters and miscellaneous summoned creatures are still characters in a practical sense.

Comment: The tag wiki's usage guidance suggests it's for PCs, NPCs, and monsters, so it's at least using the tag as it was intended. I think to make it more discoverable a synonym involving [creature-template] would be a good idea, in whichever direction. (To my mind monsters are characters too, so I've no preference for one or the other as more correct.)